# Terratest - how to test a terraform module which contains aws secrets manager secrets

Tags: terraform, aws-secrets-manager, terratest

Does anyone have a work around for testing a `terraform` module with `terratest` that contains a `aws secrets manager` secret.

You cant create / delete / create again the same secret, as AWS has a delay in remove the secret.

Its making tests fail that should pass

Comment: What tests are failing because of the mandatory deletion delay?

Comment: Well, you actually can, you just need to have the right argument in your terraform code: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/secretsmanager_secret#recovery_window_in_days.